# Declare a static property in an Objective-C class interface

Tags: objective-c, static, declared-property

I'm defining an Objective-C class:

```
@interface MyRequest : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSDecimalNumber *myNumber;

@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) CommConfig *commConfig;

@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) BOOL debug;
```

How do I make `commConfig` a static variable? When I use the 'class' keyword, the compiler gives me the following warning:

> Class property 'commConfig' requires method 'commConfig' to be defined - use @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation

And the constructor doesn't recognize this line anymore:

```
_commConfig = commConfig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not implemented by the programmer instance properties are automatically implemented by the compiler - an instance variable allocated and getter and/or setter methods written. Class properties are *never* automatically implemented, you therefore need to declare the static backing variable and define the getter. In your `@implementation` add:

```
static CommConfig *_commConfig;

+ (CommConfig *) commConfig { return _commConfig; }
```

You can call the backing anything you wish, e.g. to follow a naming convention for global/static variables.

HTH

Comment: Hopefully it's obvious, but might be worth noting, that you have to implement _all_ attributes of the property. I.e., if you want it to be `weak`, you must use a `__weak` backing var; if you want it to be atomic, you must lock it yourself...